# processing and comparing dates in cypher and neo4j

Tags: database, date, datetime, neo4j

I am working with a neo4j database and need to be able to have a query check if a date property in a node is before or after the current date.  Dates are passed into the database using csv files with dates in this format:  mm/dd/yyyy.

Having researched the concept, I found that neo4j does not currently support dates in its release version.  How could I get neo4j to do a query where it checks if currentDate > dateProperty  (meaning the current date is after the date in the date propert) if neo4j doesn't support dates?

I would prefer not to change the format, unless there was a way to store the date in a format that neo4j can use but display it as mm/dd/yyyy. If not, is there a way I can convert the date to a format that neo4j can use using code within the query?

Comment: The only thing worse than getting into a rabbit hole dealing with dates in a language that has them implemented, is getting into a rabbit hole dealing with dates in a language that doesn't have dates implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED with info on APOC in neo4j 3.x]

#### Original answer

This query should return all nodes that satisfy `currentDate > d.date`. It assumes that you pass a `currentDate` parameter in the same `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

```
WITH split({currentDate}, '/') AS cd
MATCH (d:Data)
WITH cd, split(d.date, '/') AS dd, d
WHERE
  (cd[2] > dd[2]) OR
  (cd[2] = dd[2] AND
    ((cd[0] > dd[0]) OR
     (cd[0] = dd[0] AND (cd[1] > dd[1]))))
RETURN d
```

NOTE 1: I use the `WITH` at the beginning so that the calculation of `cd` is only done once. If that logic had been incorporated into the other `WITH` clause (which is perfectly legal), then the `cd` collection would probably be unnecessarily recalculated for every `Data` node.

NOTE 2: This query does not need to convert each date component to an int before comparison as long as every date's format is always exactly `mm/dd/yyyy`. For example, `mm` must always be 2 numeric characters ('12' > '09' is `true`), or the query will not work as is ('12' > '9' is `false`).

#### APOC procedures added in neo4j 3.x

In neo4j 3.x, APOC procedure support was added (but it has to be installed on the neo4j server), including procedures for [date/time support](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_date_time_support).

Comment: I am assuming Data represents a node, and not just a piece of content in a node?

Comment: And why is there a with at the beginning?

Comment: Yes, `Data` is a [label](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.3/rest-api-node-labels.html#rest-api-adding-a-label-to-a-node) that can be applied to  one or more nodes. I decided to add it, in case you already had labels. See my updated answer for why there is a leading `WITH`.

Comment: I tried this, it looked very promising except when I ran it, it returned an item where the d.date was greater than currentDate.  I input 07/28/2015 as the cd, and it returned a node with a date of 11/24/2015.

Comment: [See this console](http://console.neo4j.org/r/poaqk7), which reproduces what you say you tried. As expected, the query does not return a result.

Comment: Ok, the problem was that for some reason, it was comparing the numbers in the first part of the date as individual characters, not integers (so for some reason 11/02/2015 was being read as 1/2/2015).  Fixed it by adding TOINT to all of the cd's and dd's.

Comment: Which you kind of implied with your recent edit.  However, since some of the dates the system will be using are in the format: m/d/yyyy, using TOINT provides more flexibility.

Comment: @cybersam:  how do you set the parameter? Something like `{
  "currentDate" : "01/02/2003"
}` ? This doesn't work for me.

Comment: The way you pass [parameters](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#cypher-parameters) depends on how you make the Cypher query (e.g., via the REST API, the Java API, or a "driver").

Comment: I have also added a little info on date/time APOC procedures to my answer. They may allow you to avoid using my proposed workaround.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Neo4j you have both date() and datetime() formats:

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/temporal/date/
https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/temporal/datetime/

When you set your node property, use syntax similar to this:

```
Match(n) where id(n) = 123 set n.somedatevalue = datetime("2020-06-08T13:08:00Z")
```

(There are more variations of date/datetime that can be used, refer to the doc).

You can then do (proper) comparisons of your date/datetime properties when selecting nodes.